# HTML DropDown List concatenated within a C# code, disappearing after the page refreshes?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This question is slightly different from the rest online because of the way I have coded.
I am using C# and within the program I have an HTML Dropdown List built by using datalist tag through string concatenation. So I have incorporated an HTML tag within my aspx.cs file. The dropdown list reads it's option values from an external .txt file which I load first. I am able to to this when the page first loads. I am able to select any value from the dropdown list and filter out the values too.

However whenever I refresh the page, the Dropdown list completely disappears along with the file that I just loaded.

1.I know that HTML controls do not retain postback unlike ASP controls. Hence the HTML DropDown disappears. 
2. There is no file to read from after the page refreshes so the DDL has nowhere to read values from too.

But can I prevent that from happening? I am not sure how to move ahead. I tried javascript too but couldn't figure out how to pass values from asp page to html page. Any progress in the code is greatly dependent on the value of the DDL. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you want a reference, datalist tag in pure HTML looks like the following and gives you a DDL. Below that is my own code snippet.

```html
    <input list="fruits">
    <datalist id="fruits">
      <option value="Apple">
      <option value="Orange">
      <option value="Mango">
      <option value="Kiwi">
    </datalist>
```

I am doing the same in my C# code where myFruit simply means the value that I have read from an external .txt file. I have used FileUpload Control to load the file.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
List<string> uniqueFruits = new List<string>();
var htmlDdl = "";   
htmlDdl = "<input list =\"fruits\">"; 
htmlDdl = htmlDdl + "<datalist id = \"fruits\">";
foreach (string fruit in txtfile)
    { uniqueFruits.Add(myFruit)
    htmlDdl = htmlDdl + "<option value= \"" + myFruit + "\">";
    }

htmlDdl = htmlDdl + "</datalist>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not completely in context, so I don't know for sure that you are running it on `page_load`, but I am assuming you are.

If you are running the C# snippet in `page_load`, then it should run every time you load or reload the page. Put a breakpoint in there and ensure you are getting into this code on every load.

If it *is* getting into this code on every load, then the reason it's not building your drop down list is that `txtfile` is empty. Put a breakpoint on that line and ensure that `txtfile` has all of the entries that you are expecting.

I see that you read from `myFruit`, but I don't see where you are declaring or filling it. How do you do this?

I think you say that the contents of `txtfile` is a result of an upload from the client. Perhaps you are reading once and discarding, or else there is some file locking happening to limit access to the file? You may consider persisting the serialized contents of that file elsewhere, either in a database, or in a session variable.